# How i should to solve the exception ElementNotVisibleException with selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am trying to make the test to insert indicator(funcional test with selenium) and i get a issue.

I supose that the issue is showed because initialy i am in the link "http://localhost:8000/key_process_indicator_bsc/process_indicator" and i when the button is actived , this open a new page, with diferent url and after i should fill the fields, after the new page is open, but this search in the first page and don't the last page, but i don't know how to solve this issue.

This is the code in the funcionaly test:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

#driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
class GoToLogin():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\lruedc\Downloads\chromedriver')

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver.get('http://localhost:8000/key_process_indicator_bsc/process_indicator');

    def new_indicator(self):

        #time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
        button_field_indicator = self.driver.find_element_by_id('btn_new_indicator')
        button_field_indicator.click()
        name_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_name')
        name_field.send_keys('Indicador margen de EBITDA')
        weight_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_weight')
        weight_field.send_keys('40')
        goal_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_goal')
        goal_field.send_keys('95')
        minimum_range_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_minimum_range')
        minimum_range_field.send_keys('40')
        hight_range_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_hight_range')
        hight_range_field.send_keys('80')
        responsible_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_responsible')
        responsible_field.send_keys(1)
```

The issue is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\main.py", line 60, in <module>
    go_to_login.new_indicator()
  File "D:\projects\main.py", line 46, in new_indicator
    name_field.send_keys('Indicador margen de EBITDA')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 328, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 454, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

thanks.

Comment: use explicit wat until element is visible.

Comment: after the code line (button_field_indicator.click()) i added the next code:        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        name_field =wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'id_name')))
        name_field.send_keys('Indicador margen de EBITDA')                       and i see new issue                                                                           (raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message), You can help me?

Comment: TimeoutException -- Thats not an issue, it saying the desired element wasn't clickable even after waiting for 10 sec. rather than waiting for clickable try wait for visibility.